# How to Get Property Value from a type defined in an Assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection

This is the code (I've modified it for simplicity):

```
System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Type t = asm.GetType("OneSubClass");
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("SubClassProperty");
```

After this code, `asm` is my application's exe, which has a half dozen or so classes inside it.

`t` is the type for one of those classes inside the exe.

`pi` is filled with the property info of the property within the class `OneSubClass`

When running my application, it creates instances for all these classes defined in the exe. Then the above code is executed. However, how do I get the actual *value* of the property?

If I try something like:

```
pi.GetValue(asm, null);
```

it gives me exception "object does not match target type" - I need an instance of the class I want the property from (which I'm not sure how to get - I only have `asm`)

Comment: you know you need an instance.Do you know where is that instance ?

Comment: @Selman22 yeah, I thought you could get instance information using reflection, but as Rex pointed out, it seems like that isn't possible. I'd have to think about this more.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of the `OneSubClass` class. The class (and the type) itself is just a template - it has no values for any of its properties. Each instance of the type has values, and you pass the instance into `GetValue`:

```
pi.GetValue(instanceOfOneSubClass, null);
```

One way to create an instance is using [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.activator.createinstance):

```
object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(OneSubClass));
```

But that is basically the equivalent of calling `new OneSubClass()`, so unless you know the default constructor will do exactly what you're expecting here, that's not always very useful.

> When running my application, it creates instances for all these classes defined in the exe.

I'm not exactly sure what this means. Are you saying somewhere there is already a created instance and you need to somehow get a handle to it?

Comment: @NathanA no, it doesn't. The code in the question illustrates attempting to pass an assembly into GetValue, which is not correct. IT doesn't mention instances.

Comment: Look at the very last paragraph.  `I need an instance of the class I want the property from (which I'm not sure how to get - I only have asm)`

Comment: @NathanA asm is the assembly instance, which doesn't even make any sense.

Comment: I'm not saying the code example is correct.  But he did indicate that he needs the instance in his question.

Comment: @NathanA, What about the phrase in OP `When running my application, it creates instances for all these classes defined in the exe.`?

Comment: @RexM As I'm still learning reflection, sorry for the confusion here. I tried using `CreateInstance` at one point, but it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. But the parameter for the class I'm trying to get an instance of is the very property I want! So is it not possible to get the already created instance from `asm`?

Comment: @ryrich `asm` just represents the assembly, which is all the class definitions and such. It doesn't contain any instances, just types. The AppDomain is the current process, which probably has MANY assemblies loaded and there could be tens or thousands or billions of instances of a single type. You need to start by knowing exactly which instance you want, where it is, and then we can figure out how to get a handle to it.

Comment: @RexM thanks for the help, I thought it may be possible to get instance information using reflection. I'll have to go about this another way I think.

Answer (score -1):

t is only a type, not an instance of that type.

You first have to create an instance of that type like this:

```
object asmInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

then get the value on that instance

```
pi.GetValue(asmInstance, null);
```

Answer (score -2):

You are triying to get the property from the `Assembly` class you are instantiating.

To retrieve a value from an object, you need the reference to that object:

```
object GetValueFromClass(object Class)
{

    System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Type t = asm.GetType("OneSubClass");
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("SubClassProperty");

    return pi.GetValue(Class, null);

}
```